# Does Amazon S3 have "sub-directories"? (Rackspace Cloudfiles does not)

Tags: linux, storage, cloud-computing, cdn

In Rackspace, all the "buckets" are one level.

Buckets cannot be inside other buckets.
This makes it very hard for ORGANIZATION!

**Edit: does anyone have any suggestions on which one to use...for best organization!? 
If no sub-buckets , are there any tips to organize multiple projects/files?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider installing an EC2 server with Redis or Tokyo Cabinet or Hadoop or CouchDB, and then use that to manage your S3 storage. That way to can make sub-buckets and manage them in any way that you want. Or use the Google AppEngine with [s3bucketapp](http://code.google.com/p/s3bucketapp/) that emulates S3. Or download the source code to s3bucketapp and modify it to allow for sub-buckets on your S3 bucket. There are lots of ways around this, some of which might even be commercially viable businesses.

Comment: Thanks. What would you recommend to do sub-buckets? Rackspace cloudfiles or Amazon S3 , or what?

Answer (score 4):

No but you can fake it by using "/" in the name of the resource you are placing in the bucket.  Many of the bucket browsers support this and show it as folders.

Comment: Can this be faked in Rackspace?

Comment: Most filesystems don't have sub-buckets either. They just fake it with special directory files. All the actual data storage comes out of one flat namespace of disk blocks numbered from 0 to the max.

Answer (score 0):

No, S3 has no concept of sub-buckets.

Answer (score 0):

My thought is to build a custom app using Cloud Files API that manages the hierarchy and then you can call the buckets anything you want.

What would be your use case anyway?  Depending on how you would actually be using sub-buckets, you might take a different approach.