# Which CDN do you recommend for good organization of files?

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage, cdn

I have many projects that need to be organized in sub-buckets and sub-sub-buckets.

Which CDN do you recommend?

I asked this question earlier, and some people told me to "fake" S3:
[Does Amazon S3 have "sub-directories"? (Rackspace Cloudfiles does not)](https://serverfault.com/questions/78297/does-amazon-s3-have-sub-directories-rackspace-cloudfiles-does-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be to find a content delivery network that will offer caching. You would store your files somewhere accessible via web like S3 and the CDN will fetch the files and serve them through a cname of yours. Some CDNs that can do this are Akamai and Limelight from what I know, but they probably won't touch you unless you are delivering TBs per month and can sign a contract.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Rackspace's [Cloud Files](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/files).

They have a complete API, and they are using Limelight.  They use containers so you can organize saved data into logical buckets (not directories, as they are not hierarchical).  In order to create hierarchical relationships you can either manage it in your own application that touches the API (making your own CDN in effect), and/or name your containers with underscores or other identifiers that you can parse to determine hierarchical relationship.

There's no minimum to using Cloud Files, and I'm pretty sure you can use them with or without a cloud server package.

Comment: They do have an API, but they do not offer official support for developing in it. Also, they don't support gzipping of static content- which is a real negative.